# Silverlight equivalent to an OnShow event to allow 2 stage page display

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm finding a common pattern during my WP7 development.

Something takes a long time to display and I want to break down the display into 2 parts - an initial display so I can show a Loading message and start the progress bar then a secondary display where I can load the data.

At the moment I'm trying to do this in a custom control but it could equally apply to user control or a page.

I can't find a way of doing this. Way back in WinForm days there were events I could call before the form was shown and others for after. I guess I'm looking for something similar.

I have also tried to see if I can display a stack panel first with the Loading message then capture an event on that to fire the data loading but nothing so far.

Any ideas?

I'm using Caliburn Micro BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the page's `Loaded` event or an `OnNavigatedTo` override to show the Loading message, and then you can use the [`BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to run your long-running process on a background thread so that the UI thread remains responsive, and then in the handler for the `RunWorkerCompletedEvent` handler, which is marshalled onto the UI thread for you, you can hide the loading message and perform your second stage display.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I couldn't actually do any work with the background worker as I'm creating user controls and get an exception when I try and do this from the worker thread, but it did just what I was looking for which is allow the UI thread to display the loading message.